# strange characters showing up for apostrophe in php

Tags: php, wordpress, pdf, centos

I'm using Wordpress PDF Templates Plugin.

When I am printing the content to a PDF the apostrophe prints as:

> â€™

On my dev machine this does not occur.  Is there something I can configure on my centos server to render true apostrophes?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

UTF-8 Encode the template and that will go away :)

You can try this in the top of your php code when creating the pdf

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

Comment: I added <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" /> to the header and now the puncuation is all ??? marks.  How do I get the standard punctuation to show up?